# Services in Domain Driven Desing

Tags: service, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I am bit confused about services in DDD.

First of all. Why are services always expressed as an Interface? Is that a rule?

Why do services contain only one method? Sometimes it makes sense to implement related methods in a single class.

Do I have to make services for each repository? I must be doing something wrong because I find myself making services for CRUD operations.

For example I have a repository with the usual methods. How do I control the access to the objects persisted in the repository? I tend to make services with lots of reading methods. Those services can check the user roles and then decide if the user can use the objects or not. I feel something is not good in my design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about domain services. There are other types of services in DDD such as application services and infrastructure services.

> First of all. Why are services always expressed as an Interface? Is
>   that a rule?

No this is not a rule. Only create an interface abstraction when there is a need for it.

> Why do services contain only one method? Sometimes it makes sense to
>   implement related methods in a single class.

A service with a single method can be thought of as implementing a single operation - a single use case. If it makes sense to encapsulate multiple operations in a single object than this is also acceptable. However, conflating multiple responsibilities into a single class often leads to violation of SRP.

> Do I have to make services for each repository?

No. A repository is already a sort of service. More specifically, a repository implementation can be thought of as an infrastructure service.

It is the application service which calls a repository in order to implement some use case. It delegates to domain entities and orchestrates other services that may be required for a given operation. Take a look at [Services in DDD](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) for an example of the various services interacting.